# Creating a buffer in a nasm macro?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

As you might guess, I'm new to this (both nasm and assembly, though I've done some basic assembly before).
I'm trying to create a function that prints integers to standard output. Using non-reusable code (where the number to be printed is static), I've succeeded... However, for obvious reasons, I want it to take the number to print as an argument.

I'm unsure whether a macro or a function is best for me, and I can't find much on the topic of NASM macros at all. I've read the manual quite carefully, but it's not enough.

Anyway, I've tried to do this with a NASM macro, as I created another one that prints strings with success that way.
I've narrowed down the problematic code to this:

```
%macro crash 1
jmp %%endstr
%%str: db %1,0x0a
%%endstr:
mov [%%str], byte 0x16 <<< this crashes (segmentation fault)
%endmacro

section .text
global _start
_start:
crash "abc"
```

It looks like anything that uses brackets on the buffer crashes, and I can only assume I'm doing it wrong.
What I *want* the above to do is to overwrite the first byte in %%str with another byte value. More precisely, I need to write a string to a buffer byte-by-byte backwards; I (try to) do this with a loop, where I do

```
mov [%%str+rcx], dl
dec rcx
```

until rcx is 0.

If I shouldn't use macros for this, please enlighten me!
I intend to save the function in a mini-library for later use as well, so it should be easy to pop it in to any NASM project.

As the topic and tags say, all this is under Linux/amd64.

Comment: You should make this a function, having macros spread internal state all around your code is bad style (even for assembler!). It will also aid your debugging. If you want more help on your problem at hand you should post all of the relevant code and output from gdb (`gdb ./your-program`, and capture the output of `bt` and `info reg` ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that in the code segment because it's read-only. You should declare str in the @data segment, then you'll be fine. And, just like @user786653 said, "You should make this a function, having macros spread internal state all around your code is bad style (even for assembler!)".

Comment: Damn, how did I overlook the implicit usage of the code 'segment' for data? Looking too much at old assembler code where it doesn't matter will do that I guess :) +1 Since this is almost certainly the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, now that you say it I remember. I should go through the basics again. Anyway, this is a bit confusing: [this code](https://gist.github.com/a0b75f5a28a2d079ffb7) that stores data the same way works! I assume that's just a fluke, and not something I should consider working code, then?

Comment: @exscape: That code isn't writing to the string. You can have read-only data in the code segment, you just can't (shouldn't) write there.

Answer (score 0):

for in a section .data

; use name and number of bytes

```
%macro BUFFER 2
%1:
   .start: times %2 db 0
   .end:
   .length: equ %1.end-%1.start
%endmacro
```

for in section .bss

; use name and number of bytes

```
%macro BUFFER 2
%1:
    .start: resb %2
    .end:
    .length: equ %1.end-%1.start
%endmacro
```

problem here is that is we want to know the last byte of the buffer then it is buffer.end-
1
a possible solution but I didn't try it yet:

```
%macro BUFFER 2
%1:
    .start: times %2-1 db 0
    .end: db 0
    .length: equ %1.end-%1.start
%endmacro
```

idem for .bss section

```
%macro BUFFER 2
%1:
    .start: resb %2-1
    .end: resb 1
    .length: equ %1.end-%1.start
%endmacro
```